# Don’t open page on click on content

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I just started a WP website maintenance with lots of custom code.

On the single page, when you click on content, you’re redirected to partner website (that’s ads).

I searched everywhere on FTP and code but can’t find where to locate the functionality to delete It.

You can see it here on clicking anywhere in the article content: https://www.neufmois.fr/ma-grossesse/enceinte-quel-est-linteret-du-vaccin-contre-la-grippe

Do you have an idea or a clue to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has to do with the markup of the HTML and CSS.

.habillage_bod has an link refering to: 'bit.ly/2BzgR60'

Seeing an part of script:

```
function click_habillage() {
  window.location.href="bit.ly/2BzgR60";
}
```

Having also an position absolute with height 1000, overal most of the screen heights.

Answer (score 0):

To find a click handler:

Open your page in Google Chrome. Right click any part you say opens the other page by clicking on it > `Inspect element`. Go to the `Elements` tab (if not already on it), right click the part of the code that has a blue/grey background. Now on the right side click on the `Event Listeners` tab. On this tab, open the `v click` part, here you see a list of the click handlers of the element that you right clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" style="z-index: 0 !important;" onclick="click_habillage()">
```

That `click_habillage()` function makes the redirection.